# C++ : how do I make the program exactly like in the picture?

Tags: c++

[image: the result should be like this:]

*Buatlah program untuk menghitung perkalian deret bilangan genap membentuk segitiga siku terbalik dengan hasil seperti pada gambar di atas.

my program is like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, n;
    for(i=0; i<5; puts(""),++i)
    {
        n=0;
        for(j=5; j>i; n+=2*(j--))
        {
            if(j>i+1) {
                printf("%d * ",2*j);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d ",2*j);
            }
        }
        printf("\t= %d",n);
    }
    printf("\t\t110");
    return(0);
}
```

how do I make the program exactly like in the picture above?

Comment: Book-keeping. You'll have to compute where the first line placed the answer and make certain that you pad each subsequent line to reach place its answer at the same position.

Comment: Note: the only header used in this program is `<stdio.h>`. If you are expected to need them, you may be straying from the intended goals of this assignment.

Comment: Please describe the differences between what you get and what you want in detail. That is the first step towards removing the differences. Also, just for our sake, please show what you get, so that we can cross-check your description.

Comment: I think the most striking difference can be removed by replacing `" * "` with `" + "`. Are there more differences you want removed? If the `"*"` is intentional, then you should adapt the desired output, by replacing it with text you wrote yourself, in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code gives the output you stated in your question. I'm not sure though if you are intended to do it like this, since there might be a smarter solution using iomanip and iostream, because you included it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, n;
    for(i=0; i<5; puts(""),++i)
    {
        n=0;
        for(j=5; j>i; n+=2*(j--))
        {
            if(j>i+1) {
                printf("%d + ",2*j);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d ",2*j);
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) printf("    ");
        printf("= %d",n);
    }
    printf("\t\t    ---------- +\n");
    printf("\t\t\t 110\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm try to use iomanip and iostream but the result not same with picture.. by the way thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    int i,  k, n, s=0;

    for(k=2; k <= 10; k+=2) {
        n=0;
        for(i=10; k <= i; i-=2) {
            if (k < i)
                cout<<i<<" + " ;
            else {
                cout<< i;
                cout.width(k*2);
                cout<< right<< " = ";
            }
            n+=i;
        }
    cout<<n<<"\n";
    s += n;
    }
    cout<< "------------------------- +"<<"\n";
    cout<< "                     "<<s<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This lacks the padding spaces before `=`.

Comment: how to do that?